# Video Streaming in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, video, streaming, video-streaming

I am designing a table view that consist of a video streaming in it.
First of all, think of my application as a video streaming application. There will be video queries and users will watch them. 
My question is that now I'm downloading the videos in table view cell, therefore whenever user scrolls into a video, it starts to download. But after going to another video and turning to the first one again, it downloads the first video again. This is not efficient for both user and our backend. How can we solve this problem? Maybe we could save some part of the videos in a temporary memory. Since we are developing an application for the first time, feel free to give an advice.

Here is my table view cell code snippet.

```
func explore() {
var asset = AVAsset(URL: tableVideoURL)
        var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = newRect
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
        contentView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()

}
```